# How to make that user can input integer or character with scanf

Tags: c

I am trying to make a program that user can enter either an integer or character. And then the binary representation of the input will be printed. (ASCII code for chars). But only one of them works when I try to fix it.

Comment: An example of your code would be helpful.

Comment: If the user enters 9, how do you know whether they want the number or the character?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `scanf` if you don't know whether it should parse the input as an integer or a character.

Therefore, I suggest you first read the whole line with [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) instead and then determine afterwards whether it is an integer or a character that was entered, for example by using the function [`isdigit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isdigit). Afterwards you can act accordingly, for example by calling [`sscanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf), [`atoi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/atoi), [`strtol`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) or whatever function you want on the input.

Answer (score 0):

Does this answer to your question?

```
#include<stdio.h>

void decToBinary(int n) 
{ 
    int binaryNum[32];  // array to store binary number 

    // counter for binary array 
    int i = 0; 
    while (n > 0) 
    { 

        binaryNum[i] = n % 2; 
        n = n / 2; 
        i++; 
    } 

    // printing binary array in reverse order 
    for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--) 
        printf("%d",binaryNum[j]); 
} 

int main()
{
    char a;
    char ch;
    int b,num;
    printf("What do you want to enter: character(C/c) or number(N/n) :");
    scanf("%c",&a);
    if((a=='C')||(a=='c'))
    {   
        printf("\nEnter the character:");
        scanf(" %c",&ch);
        b=ch;       
        printf("\nASCII VALUE : %d",b);
    }
    else if((a=='N')||(a=='n'))
    {
        printf("\nEnter the number:");
        scanf("%d",&num);
        decToBinary(num);
    }
    else
        printf("Invalid entry!!");
    return 0;
}
```